# Displaying blank box instead of blank space while using marathi even after declaration of UTF-8 in meta tag

Tags: html, css

[image]

At default zoom level i.e 100% sometimes I get this problem of blank boxes instead of blank spaces but when I change the zoom level it looks normal.
Somebody please tell me why this is happening?

My all rest code which is in marathi is working fine.
I have used unicode for displaying marathi and I have include meta tag for that also then why this is happening?

Comment: Post at least some code, preferably a minimal self-contained document that reproduces the problem. And identify where you see blank boxes (I cannot see anything in the image that looks like a blank box).

Comment: What is the base font you are setting?

Comment: @ Jukka : blank boxes are highlighted in red circles

Comment: @ Praveen : I'm using Mangle font

Comment: Ah, that's where the problem is then. Try using a Unicode Font. :)

Comment: but Mangal is it self unicode font na...

Comment: because I haven't set [style="font-family: 'Magal'"] anywhere in my page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is with the base font setting. So, try using this:

```
<div style="font-family: 'Arial Unicode MS';">तुम्हारा नाम क्या है?</div>
```

Comment: i have used <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> and then i directly pasted my MARATHI text in page and its working for other data except sometime for my page header